# Sitecore Renderings Sorting

Tags: presentation

We have complex requirement where we want to sort the renderings at run time based on Filters For example : Assume that we have controller renderings say BC1,BC2,BC3,BC4 in sequence mentioned. Now problem this

Now we have filters in system where based on filtration BC1 may get removed and BC2 will take position of BC1 also BC3 will get position of BC2 and so on

Can some body help me with possible design

Regards
UG

Comment: Are all of these controller renderings in the same placeholder? If so, this sounds like the default behavior to me. Maybe I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes all of these are controller renderings this is not a default behavior as rendering position of BC1 will be taken by Rendering BC2 post filtration we need to  change Rendering Order at runtime based on Filters

Comment: If these renderings are all bound to the same placeholder and one of the renderings is removed at runtime, then the renderings that were after it would "shift up". If you are seeing different behavior, then please include additional information about how your renderings are placed.

Comment: Sorry what i forget to mention was in between BC1,BC2 and BC3 we have other renderings as well say CC1,CC2 and CC3 so overall rendering on layout are in this order : CC1,BC1,CC2,BC2,CC3,BC3,CC4,BC4 so postion of CC1 ,CC2,,CC3,CC4 is fixed where as based  on filters rendering position of BC1 will be taken by Rendering BC2 post filtration. So challenge here is how do inject rendering BC2 in position of BC1 at runtime

Comment: Can you elaborate on your filters? Is it only the B1 component which can be removed? Or maybe you can remove both B1 and B2 (or B1 and B3), and all the other B# components should "move up"? Are filters based on some user actions or "static" like url parameters?

Comment: Filters are dropdown which has some Categories and Brands and based on these values selected any of the Renderings out ,BC1,BC2,,BC3,,BC4 can get removed say BC1,or BC2 or BC1,BC2 and BC3 and next available rendering will move up and in between we have other renderings as well position of those renderings is fixed.

Comment: And it's not just javascript client side action - you have the page fully rendered again, correct?

Comment: It's an Ajax Call and we are not loading full page again

Comment: Does the ajax call response contain the UniqueIds of the renderings which should be displayed / hidden? Is it possible that after one ajax call you hide B1 component, then you do another ajax call and B1 component should be back and B2 component should be move back to it's original position?

Comment: Unfortunately we have one Ajax call only

Comment: So when the page is rendered on the server side, you are not removing any renderings. The renderings are only removed via JavaScript. Is that correct?

Comment: I am down-voting the question because it omitted quite a lot of information as is shown in the comments. Please update the question to clearly explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Every B# Component (B1, B2, B3...) should have a cshtml file like:

```
<input type="hidden" data-selector="dynamic-component-placeholder" />
<div data-selector="dynamic-component" data-componentid="@Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.UniqueId">
    <!-- COMPONENT CONTENT -->
</div>
```

1. On document ready (assuming that you're using jQuery), create a list containing all the `dynamic-component-placeholder` hidden inputs.
2. On document ready, create a list containing all the `dynamic-component` components.
3. When Ajax call request returns response, remove all the `dynamic-component` components from the dom, create temporary list of filtered `dynamic-component` components and add them one by one AFTER the subsequent `dynamic-component-placeholder`.